# My Sculpt Tool Isn't Working

Tags: sculpt-mode

I've looked at many other different questions on this site as well as youtube videos and googled the problem, but either a solution doesn't work, or the step made 0 sense. I'm trying to make a model, but in order for it to look good, I need to use the sculpt mode (such as you have object mode, there is sculpt mode). But every time I try to grab, smooth, or do anything to my model, absolutely nothing happens. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you please share your object? At least a part of it..

Comment: I have experienced a bug matching the description with WeightedNormal modifier. It is fixed in the newest version. Any chance you might be using older version and WeightedNormal modifier?